# How to make Codeigniter Search (Dynamic Website) Content like Google Custom Search

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, sitemap, google-custom-search

I am trying to make a search that will search for news, events with my menu links.  The website whole data, that may include content inside pages.
 I cannot make search using database search because links are different and multiples.

I have tried HTML sitemap but unable to make HTML sitemap so I can search through that.  It will also provide link with data.

Comment: News events your your own website?

Comment: i am trying to develop website search that will search all my content in the website.not from database.

Comment: May this help you:-

   https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-in-files

https://github.com/cebe/js-search

Comment: In files case i am unable to create links.I want to create a Search that will go through all data in the website but it will work on Frontend.
Because on the Backend Work there are several links which we can't put in the Search Manually.